# Is it possible to host a local HTTPS website using existing website certifacate

Tags: ssl, https, xampp, localhost, wamp

For example, let's say there is a website named `www.example.com` that uses HTTPS for a secure connection, and I create a local website using `xampp` or `wamp`, then I map this one to `www.example.com` (using `hosts` in windows for example). Can I cheat an application that connects to `www.example.com` to make it connect to my local website using `www.example.com` (of course, by activating SSL service on my local web-server)?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course, you just need to have the certificate private key configured on your local server.

There is lots of website usign the same hostname & certificate with various IP (mostly for load balancing purposes).

Comment: Ah great, but the website `www.example.com` is not hosted by me, how can I get its certificate and configure on my local server?

Comment: To obtain such certificate, you have to be an administrator of www.example.com.... (this is why https make man in the middle attack far more complicated)... A better option may be to check how the application you want to hack manage certificates (if you can add certification authorities - so you can add your own)... But without knowing the application it's quite hard to answer